# Parsing a .NET DataGridView with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to parse the grid in this dialog using AutoHotKey:
http://f.imagehost.org/0423/Screenshot.png

It's a modal dialog from a .Net application.. Using Reflector I've been able to find that the grid is a  System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.

I can easily parse the text cells using a hackish Send/Clipboard combination, but I need to tell apart the icons of the first column too.. Is there a way to do that using AutoHotKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I ended up using a combination of PixelSearch (to locate the current row) and ImageSearch to detect which image is displayed.. Hackish but it works.